# scanf formatted multiple special characters with array

Tags: c, scanf, special-characters, formatted-input

I want to have 3 inputs of symbols  e.g. `|` or `%`, but instead of getting `| | %`, I got `| |`.

Terminal:

```
| ^ !

 | ^
```

The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[10], b[10], c[10];
int i;
int count;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scanf("%c %c %c", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]);
        printf("%c %c %c\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: That snippet of code works fine for me. Can you add the entire source of your program, as well as copy and paste the exact input and output, including where you hit Enter?

Comment: `if (scanf(...) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: `scanf("%c %c %c"` --> `scanf(" %c %c %c"`  Add space.  Else `&a[i]` is a linefeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read single characters symbols optionally separated by whitespaces, you must explicitly ignore this whitespace with a  in the format string before the `%c`.

Also check the return value of `scanf()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char a[10], b[10], c[10];
    int i, count;

    if (scanf("%d", &count) == 1 && count <= 10) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (scanf(" %c %c %c", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]) != 3)
                break;
            printf("%c %c %c\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.